# PYODBC Cannot find driver for MSSQL

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc, unixodbc

I am attempting to connect to SQL Server using a simple python script that looks like the following.

```
import pyodbc

details = {
    'server': '<hostname>',
    'database': '<database>',
    'username': '<username>',
    'password': '<password>'
}

connect_string = 'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER={server};PORT=1443;DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}'.format(**details)

connection = pyodbc.connect(connect_string)
print(connection)
```

The only difference is that I have removed the config value for obvious reasons. However, when I run this script I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect.py", line 12, in <module>
    connection = pyodbc.connect(connect_string)
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

For reference the output of runnning `odbcinst -j` gives me:

```
unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/bipvanwinkle/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

`cat /etc/odbcinst.ini`:

```
[SQLServer]
Description     = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver          = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.1
UsageCount      = 1
FileUsage       = 1
```

`cat /etc/odbc.ini`:

```
[SQLServer]
Description     = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver          = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so
Servername      =
Database        =
UID             =
Port            = 1433
```

`ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so`:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so

`ldd /usr/lib/x86_64llinux-gnu/libodbc.so`:

```
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc86bec000)
        libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f9841306000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f98410e7000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9840cf6000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9840af2000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f984177d000)
```

If it helps, both /etc/odbcinst.ini and /etc/odbc.ini were initially empty. I used a template I found online to fill them out. I definitely could have made errors.

Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

P.S. I'm running this on Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the output from `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so`

Comment: @GordThompson I have added the output to ldd.